# using the & char in xml/xsl file

Tags: xml

my xml file has the example tag with

```
<tag>value&value</tag>
```

there is an error when start the xsl file...

I use also &amp and the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

but not ok

Thanks!

Comment: You need to explain what "not ok" means. What is not working? Are you getting errors? It the output not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `&` to `&amp;` in XML and XSLT:

```
<tag>value&amp;value</tag>
```